# ScheduledExecutorService does not show the change in variable

Tags: java, servlets, scheduledexecutorservice

I have been trying to execute a code with the delay of 1 second in my java servlet. I need to check the condition if the tracking is on or off. If it is off then it goes to else and shuts the scheduler. The code is as under.

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Map m=request.getParameterMap();
    Set s = m.entrySet();
    Iterator it = s.iterator();
    int index=0;

        while(it.hasNext()){

            Map.Entry<String,String[]> entry = (Map.Entry<String,String[]>)it.next();

            String key             = entry.getKey();
            String[] value         = entry.getValue();

            System.out.println("Value is "+value[0].toString());
                     switch(key)
                     {
                     case "RegId": 
                         RegId=value[0].toString();
                         break;
                     case "isTrackingRequested": 
                         isTrackingRequested=Boolean.valueOf(value[0]);
                         break;     
         }
     }
    boolean isTrackingRequestednew=isTrackingRequested;
    ScheduledExecutorService ses = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();

        ses.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
            @Override 
            public void run() { 

                // code to run 
                if(isTrackingRequestednew){
                    try {
                        System.out.println("===========================================================================");
                        System.out.println("new track status is "+isTrackingRequestednew);
                        System.out.println("===========================================================================");

                        }catch(Exception e)
                        {   

                        } 
                     }
                else
                {
                    ses.shutdown();

                }
            } 
        }, 0, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}
```

Now in order to stop the tracking my application send the isTrackingRequestednew as "false", now this value is not getting changed at all. I dont know why is that happening. Please help me.

Comment: The flag is local to this method, so, it will change with every request. Also, I think the logic to schedule/stop the tasks should be in a separate class rather than in servlet and should be controlled by an instance variable.

Comment: @Darshan Mehta if i create instance variable and delegate the task to some class method, it will form new object for every request(one for turning "on" and another for turning "off"). I need to handle the switching off functionality for the same user which wont be possible if i create the object and delegate everytime. I hope you got my point.

Comment: @DarshanMehta also i thought the same thing, but the value of the variable does not change.

Comment: Can you share the full code? Where have we declared 'isTrackingRequested' flag?

Comment: @DarshanMehta the value of the isTrackingRequested comes from the mobile app and is very much accurate. The flag isTrackingRequested shows the change but the variable isTrackingRequestednew does not.

Comment: @DarshanMehta is there anyway the compiler is implicitly treating the variable isTrackingRequestednew  as final?

Comment: I was about to comment the same. If a local variable is used in anonymous class, it has to be final. Compiler should show an error if the variable is not final.

Answer (score 1):

This code would not compile, you can't access local (not final) variable inside inner class.
Every time on post request you create new ExecutorService, instead of creating it once per session or tracking entity. I don't know what is the purpose of this thread, so I would save your weird code style

```
private static class TrackingInfo {
    final private AtomicBoolean status;
    final private ScheduledExecutorService ses;

    TrackingInfo(boolean flagStatus) {
        this.status = new AtomicBoolean(flagStatus);
        this.ses = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
        ses.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                // code to run
                if (status.get()) {
                    try {
                        System.out.println("===========================================================================");
                        System.out.println("new track status is " + status.get());
                        System.out.println("===========================================================================");

                    } catch (Exception e) {

                }
                } else {
                    ses.shutdown();
                }
            }
        }, 0, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

    public void setStatus(boolean status) {
        this.status.set(status);
    }
}
```

use either `request.getSession().getAttribute(...) / setAttribute()` to hold this TrackingInfo and worker inside it and pass flag changes to worker by `TrackingInfo.setStatus(newStatus)` instance, or you can have some Map variable in your controller class (not method local variable) and store tracking id and `TrackingInfo` associated with it. 
Imho, if your real terminating of tracking thread is as simple as it is in posted code

```
else {
    ses.shutdown();
}
```

you don't need `TrackingInfo` at all. Simply store (in session or cache as it is described above) reference to the scheduler and than you receive `isTrackingRequestednew` with false value in your `doPost` method, get this scheduler and shutdown it like this

```
if (!isTrackingRequestednew) {
    ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = (ScheduledExecutorService) request.getSession().getAttribute("trackingScheduler");
    if (scheduler != null) {
        scheduler.shutdown();
    }
}
```

Instead `"trackingScheduler"` you can use some tracking id as identifier and send it with every request. 
Note that you also have to cleanup old schedulers which were not shutdowned properly due some network errors or whatever.

Comment: As to what you are suggesting here, i see you have created a new class. Now since it is a servlet, if i need to access this class method, i need to create an object and then access it. By doing so, i will end up creating new object everytime i post any request to the servlet. Hence i would not be able to stop the scheduler since i don't have access to the previous object.

Comment: No, as i said `use either request.getSession().getAttribute(...) / setAttribute() to hold this TrackingInfo ` and `or you can have some Map` in your servlet. Create once and access it numerous times.